# Database creation error: Access denied - Odoo 14 on Mac ox BigSure

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am a beginner on odoo and I then installed by watching installation tutorials.
My problem is that I can't create a database on the odoo interface, and I don't know where is my master password for the creation and deletion of a database.
Here is the content of my odoo.conf
I use a mac ox Big Sure
Please help me.
[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m818.png)
[img 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYnq.png)
[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NueG8.png)
[img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUY5a.png)

Comment: Please just add the config content as text instead of images. Nobody wants to look into images to get some text...

Comment: Ah and `admin_passwd` is the option you're searching for. Just set something to have a master password.

Comment: Please remove the comment from admin_passwd by removing semi-colon and save the config file and restart the server and then again create the database.

Answer (score 1):

in your config file (odoo.conf) remove (;) from admin_password to active it.

```
admin_passwd = yourpassword
```

and restart your server, then in the creation form add yourpassword in the Master Password field.